# Share data between Windows Phone apps

Tags: windows-phone

I'm looking for the most simple and elegant way to share data between two **separate** Windows Phone Apps.

For example, I have two apps:

1. `Input.app` - An app with an input field and a "Save"-button
2. `Read.app` - An app with a label and a "Read"-button.

The use case will be as follows:

1. The user opens the `Input.app`, enters something in the input field and presses the "Save"-button.
2. The user closes `Input.app`.
3. The user opens `Read.app` and presses the "Read"-button.
4. The label will get filled with the data stored by the `Input.app`.

**Note**

I'm not looking for a solution where `Input.app` calls the `Read.app` (for example with `Tasks`). Also, I'm not looking for a solution where `Input.app` stores the data online, and `Read.app` reads the data when the app is launched.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not at the moment. Applications are sandboxed by default and you cannot break the sandbox. There are only two ways of communicating between the applications, but neither will work for you (using URI-s and file extensions).

Isolated Storage is *isolated*, hence the name. Unfortunately, there is no "Shared" storage, not even between the applications made by the same publisher.

Maybe this will change in the upcoming Windows Phone 8.1, who knows. If you want, you can go to http://wpdev.uservoice.com and request that particular feature.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have any (official) sources to back this up? It's too bad this isn't possible (yet)...

Comment: How can I back up a negative claim? There is no such feature nor it is documented on MSDN.

Comment: Maybe there was already an official feature request at Microsoft, or something else that could back this up. Yet, since I've already looked around a lot as well, I'll have to assume it really isn't possible. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Anyone knows if this is implemented/solved for WP8.1?

Comment: No, it is fixed in Windows 10 though.